# Ajax file upload rest returns 415

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I created simple HTML form for file upload:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" id="upload-file"> 
      <input id="file" class="browse-files-button" value="Browse" type="file" name="files"></input>
</form>
```

And here is my ajax call:

```
var data = new FormData(AJS.$('#upload-file')[0]);
 AJS.$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: getAttachmentUrl(),
        data: file,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: {
        "X-Atlassian-Token": "nocheck"
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log("Error while uploading file!");
        },
        success : function(result){
            console.log("File successfully uploaded!");
        }
    });
```

And in the result i'am receiving response 415 that indicates that 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Comment: A 415 error generally means that the filetype you're uploading is not want the API wants, or is expecting to receive. Check the API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that server wants to receive a file parameter with name "file" but i sent as "files".

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" id="upload-file"> 
      <input id="file" class="browse-files-button" value="Browse" type="file" name="file"></input>
</form>
```